# SQLite database structure for time series

Tags: database, sqlite, time-series, structure, series

My VB.NET application produces simulation data which I want to store in an SQLite Database. The data consists of hundreds of variables which have values for up to 50k time steps (occurrences/measurements). Number of variables is variable. Time steps can vary from 10 to 50k.

So far, I have one table. The first column contains the timestamp (primary key) and the following contain variable values for each variable (column name = variable name). The rows are filled with the timestamps and the variable values for each time step:

```
timestamp | var1    | var2    | var3    | ...
----------------------------------------------  
1         | var1(1) | var2(1) | var3(1) | ...  
2         | var1(2) | var2(2) | var3(2) | ...  
3         | var1(3) | var2(3) | var3(3) | ...  
...       | ...     | ...     | ...     | ...
```

I use:

```
CREATE TABLE variables(timestamp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, var1 REAL, var2 REAL, ...);
```

This works. I use the database to save the simulation data for later evaluation. I need to plot selected time series and copy the values of some variables for specific time spans to Excel  (calculate sums, maxima, etc.).

I've read not to add too many columns (I may have more than 500 variables/columns). Regarding performance, is it better to structure it differently? For example one table with four columns: `ID (primary key)`, `timestamp`, `variable name` and `variable value`.

```
ID | timestamp | varName | varValue
------------------------------------  
1  | 1         | var1    | var1(1)  
2  | 2         | var1    | var1(2)  
...| ...       | ...     | ...  
50 | 50        | var1    | var1(50)  
51 | 1         | var2    | var2(1)  
52 | 2         | var2    | var2(2)  
...| ...       | ...     | ...
```

In this case I would have 50k time steps * 500 variables = 25 million rows, but a fixed number of columns. Is there any better way?

What happens regarding performance (for read queries) if I have inserted the rows not in ascending `timestamp` order?

Comment: There's also an intermediate option. TimeStamp, indicator, values1-n. e.g.indicator 1-10 and 50 value columns. inidcator being used to differentiate the sets. Another way would be to have 1 column holding all values e.g. as CSV (comma separated values).

Comment: If you want to discuss structure please show `.schema` of the relevant tables or, better, `.dump` of a tailored toy database.

Comment: @MikeT CSV-like values to represent multiple information is likely to become a problem later.

Comment: I don't think a CSV-like representation will be easy for many read and write queries.
@Yunnosch: I am new to SQlite and databases. I am not familiar with .schema and .dump. Could you elaborate on that a bit? I thought the tables above show pretty much the idea of my present concept and the idea of changing it..
Today, I tried to use the second approach. It turned out to be less performant than my first approach since I have to insert a lot more rows into the table.

Comment: When using SQLite it is possible to access the database file with the SQLite command line tool (at least if you can get the file on a PC). This allows to test queries directly in SQL syntax. It also allows to use certain non-SQL commands. Among that is `.dump` which will output some SQL syntax lines which are suitable for creating the database from scratch. That makes for about 90% of quite a useful MCVE.

Comment: Ok thank you for the info. The .dump leaves me with the same statement I wrote above: CREATE TABLE variables(timestamp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, var1 REAL, var2 REAL, ...); only that the statement is much longer since there are several hundreds of variables (=columns).
This is followed by INSERT statements: INSERT INTO variables VALUES(val1, val2, val3,.....);